# Running MongoDB commands between different versions (local vs. server)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoimport

I need to use a command (mongoimport --mode merge flag) which is only available in mongodb 3.4.x or later versions.

However I need to apply it in a production server database running a version 2.6.9 of mongodb.

I tested it against our staging environment server running with version 2.6.9 and it seems to work fine, but I'm afraid of having missed/realized anything that possibly has broken in that process.

So I want to be sure I'm not gonna mess everything up if I run mongodb commands from my local machine running MongoDB 3.4.x to the server running 2.6.9.

Does anybody tried and tested that before so that can sinalize me if I can do it confident and unconcerned?

I would really love to hear from you guys, thanks!